# Efeito hover em um elemento afetar outro

Tags: css, css-hover

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que o evento **:hover** em um elemento faça efeito em outro... Tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<ul>
  <a href="#">
     <li>
        <div id="search-image"><img src="images/image.jpg"/></div>
        <h1>Título</h1>
        <div id="search-bottom">
           <p class="price"><b>R$</b> XXX</p>
           <p class="deal">Texto</p>
           <p class="date">xx/xx/xx</p>
        </div>
     </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Gostaria de colocar uma borda e mudar a cor do título `h1` ao ter o efeito *hover* no elemento `<li>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observando que o `h1` está dentro do `li`, você pode fazer com CSS puro.
Por exemplo:

```
li:hover h1 {
    /*aqui o seu estilo para H1*/
}
```

Veja funcionando:

```css
li:hover h1 {
  border: 2px solid #FFFF00;
  color: #ff0000;
}

li:hover img {
  transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a href="#">
    <li>
      <div id="search-image">
        <img src="images/image.jpg" />
      </div>
      <h1>Título</h1>
      <div id="search-bottom">
        <p class="price"><b>R$</b> XXX</p>
        <p class="deal">Texto</p>
        <p class="date">xx/xx/xx</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

quando colocar o cursor sobre o li, o h1 e o img terão seu estilo alterado.

Comment: É possível usar css puro também para afetar elementos que não sejam filhos do elemento que recebe o hover, desde que seja possível referenciá-lo. Um exemplo seria utilizando o + para referenciar uma tag que seja "irmã" da tag que recebe o hover.

Comment: Obrigado, eu vou estilizar esse elemento Li e colocar uma border ao redor dele, só que quando ocorre o efeito hover ele meio que distorce, como nesse exemplo que você fez, como faço pra deixar imóvel? E Obrigado de novo :)

Comment: E como fazer esse efeito em mais de um elemento? por exemplo, gostaria de aumentar o tamanho da imagem dentro da div "search-image" com o transform: scale() no efeito hover no elemento li também.

Comment: A ideia é a mesma: `li:hover img { /*estilo da imagem*/ }`, Editei a resposta, olha lá

Answer (score 4):

Basta você usar o `hover` na definição do elemento que você quer alcançar no CSS. Pense no `hover` como um pseudo atributo do elemento. Ele de facto serve para identificar qualquer elemento da mesma forma que uma classe serviria. Ao contrário do hábito mais corriqueiro, o `hover` não precisa ser necessariamente usado no final da definição.

Neste caso, para colocar uma borda fina e prateada e tornar o título `h1` azul por exemplo, o código seria o seguinte:

```
li:hover h1{
    border: solid thin silver;
    color: blue;
}
```

O mesmo vale para os outros pseudo elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Uma classe chamando outra após passa o mouse encima no css

```css
.imagemfundo{
    height: 221px;
    background-color:blue;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    align-items: center;
    width: 221px;
    
}    
.textocentro{
    
    display:none;
}

.imagemfundo:hover .tituloimagen{
    
 display:block;
 font-size: 18px;
 align-items: center;
 height: 180px;
 width:180px;
 background: red;
 margin: 20px;
 border-radius: 221px;
 display: flex;
position: absolute;

}

.imagemfundo:hover .textocentro{
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   left: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagemfundo">
    
    
  <div class="tituloimagen">
  
    <div class="textocentro">
       texto 
        
    </div>
    
</div>    
    
    
</div>
```