# Em CSS, como faço para, ao dar um "hover" em um texto, a imagem dê um "scale(xx)" e sublinhe o texto?

Tags: css, html5

Além do texto sublinhar, como faço para que, ao mesmo tempo em que isso ocorrer, a imagem dê um scale(xx)? A imagem e o texto possuem classes diferentes no meu arquivo CSS. Só preciso de um norte, uma maneira de proceder.

[image: Imagem exemplificativa da minha questão]

Comment: Coloca seu código pra nós, que ai sim podemos ajudar você não só dando um norte como possivelmente resolvendo seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como um código não foi postado, da uma olhada nesse exemplo, acho que é isso que você procura.

invés de ser uma `div`, vai ser uma imagem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    transition: transform .2s;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(1.5); 
}
.zoom:hover span{
 text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>
<p>Hover over the div element.</p>
  
<div class="zoom"><span>Texto</span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta. Com o que você apresentou foi o suficiente e também acabei por encontrar o seu exemplo de outra maneira no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90199/efeito-hover-em-um-elemento-afetar-outro

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu, se possível marca minha resposta como principal.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seja isso que você está procurando:

```css
img:hover { 
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

h3:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygG9V.png" alt="BolsoMito">
</div>

<div>
    <h3>
      Bolsonaro e sua equipe nos ajudará a sair dessa crise.
    </h3>
</div>
```

Esse código te dará um norte, está separado no que cada coisa faz.
Veja que dentro do `hover` você adiciona o que você gostaria de fazer com o elemento selecionado antes do `hover` nesses casos, as tags `img`e `h3`.

É simples, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu consegui a solução no exemplo anterior ao seu. De qualquer forma muito obrigado.